# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read properties file and got stuck with error which is given below.I have written an Scala package where i'm trying to read properties file and call into abc.scala program.Any help will be appreciated.

File:- xyz.properties

```
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521/xxxx.xxxx"
username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"
input_file = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\test\\src\\main\\resources\\xxxx.xlsx"
```

build.sbt

```
name := "xxx.xxxx.xxxxx"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

ivyScala := ivyScala.value map{ _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
"com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
"org.apache.commons" % "commons-configuration2" % "2.1.1",
"commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.3",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-xml" % "2.11.0-M4"  )
```

Package

```
package com.xxx.zzzz.xxx1

        import java.io.File
        import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.{Configurations, Parameters}


        object Configuration {

          var config = new Configurations()
          var configs = config.properties(new File("xyz.properties"))

          var inputFile = configs.getString("input")
          var userName = configs.getString("user_name")
          var password = configs.getString("passwd")
          var driver = configs.getString("driver")
          var url = configs.getString("Url")

        }
```

Main Program abc.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import package com.xxx.zzzz.xxx1.Configurations
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils


object ItalyPanelData {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        //Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF)

        println("Inside main program"+ Configuration.driver)
        //Set the properties for spark to connect the oracle database
        val dbProp = new java.util.Properties
        dbProp.setProperty("driver", Configuration.driver)
        dbProp.setProperty("user", Configuration.userName)
        dbProp.setProperty("password", Configuration.password)


        //Create a connection to connect spark
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    //exception handlying
    try {
      //Create dataframe boject
      val df = sqlContext.read
        .option("location", Configuration.inputFile)        //Initiating input path
        .option("sheetName", "xyz")                       //Give the SheetName
        .option("useHeader", "true")                        //It takes the header name from excel sheet
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("addColorColumns", "false")
        .load()
      // Write into oracale database
      df.write.mode("append").jdbc(Configuration.url, "xyz", dbProp)
    }
    catch {

        case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace();
    }

      }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(Lorg/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector;)V
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.initBeanUtilsBean(BeanHelper.java:631)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.<clinit>(BeanHelper.java:89)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:294)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.fileBased(Parameters.java:185)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:602)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:614)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileBasedBuilder(Configurations.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.propertiesBuilder(Configurations.java:238)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.properties(Configurations.java:282)
at com.rxcorp.italy.config.Configuration$.<init>(Configuration.scala:8)
at com.rxcorp.italy.config.Configuration$.<clinit>(Configuration.scala)
at com.rxcorp.paneldataloading.ItalyPanelData$.main(abc.scala:12)
```

Comment: Just wondering:did my answer help you on the end? If so, please consider accepting at some point.

Answer (score 5):

Such exceptions are an indication of a version incompatibility.

Meaning: the code that you have written (or more likely: the one of the libraries under the surface) wants to call a method

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.addBeanIntrospector(BeanIntrospector[]);
```

but the thing is: at **runtime**, the class file for PropertyUtilsBean does not contain that method.

Thus: you have to step back and understand the components in your stack, and check out their version requirements on the Apache commons library.

And you get more ideas when looking into the javadoc for that [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html#addBeanIntrospector-org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanIntrospector-); as it says: **Since: 1.9** there.

In other words: this method was added Apache commons 1.9; so some piece of your stack expects **at least that** version of commons; but your classpath in the JVM that executes the whole thing ... has an older version.

So: check the classpath for apache commons; and most likely you are good by simply updating to a newer version of apache commons. (and yes, maybe that will mean more "hard" debug work; as at least your *build* settings include a newer version of apache commons).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have a similar problem. Apache commons configuration 2.7 is used in our project together with apache commons BeanUtils 1.9.
Unfortunately another library we use is jxls-reader 2.0.+ and this one references commons-digester3 library.

So the beanutils 1.9 as well as the commons-digester3 lib both have a class packaged org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean. But commons-digester3's version does not have the above mentioned method bringing us to the same dilemma as you have.
For now we can be lucky as our windows servers loading the "correct" version of beanutils first whereas some developers using a mac have it the other way round where the digester3 package is loaded first bringing up the no-such-method-error you have.

Not sure what can be our workaround here.

Anyway check if you have the class two times on your classpath and find out who's using it by checking all your pom.xmls of dependent libs on the classpath. Finally you might be lucky to remove some library if its not needed by your code (chances are low :-( though)

---

Update 10thNov: I exluded the commons-digester3 from the jxls-reader dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

So that the commons-digester with classifier "with-deps" from jxls-reader won't get resolved and I pull it in explicitely in our pom.xml but only the normal jar without packaged classes of commons-logging, commons-beanutils...